# ImportError when accessing Smartsheet

Tags: smartsheet-api

I'm receiving the error below when accessing smartsheet. What am I missing?

ERROR:smartsheet.smartsheet:ImportError! Could not load api or model class __iter_

Comment: Could you share some more information about what you were trying to do? Is there a stack trace associated with the error message?

Comment: Strange - the error has gone away and not sure why.